# if not found image, don't display image path

Tags: graphics

i want display only blank if do not found image, please don't display image path.

My minimal coding:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{file.tex}
 No,TextA
 1,Smile
 2,No
 3,


\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{poster}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{enumitem, setspace}
 \tcbset{colframe=blue!75!black,colback=white}
\DTLloaddb{file}{file.tex}
 \begin{document}

 \DTLforeach*
 {file}% Database
 {\No=No,\TextA=TextA}
 {%
 \begin{tcbposter}[
  poster = {
    columns=1,
    rows=1,
    spacing=3mm,
    height=14cm,
    width=12cm,
  },
]
%Box A

\posterbox[colframe=red,width=4.7cm,height=5.0cm]{name=A,column=1}{

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin =-1em,rightmargin =-1em]
\item \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{ImageA/\TextA.png}  \hfill abc


\end{enumerate}
}
\end{tcbposter}
\newline
}

\end{document}
```

[image]
No image like transparent, not white color
Thank in advance

Comment: Simple options ~  avoid using 3 ~ simplest of all have a whiteDummy.png and change line 3 to whiteDummy ~ not so easy to implement = use \if nul testing,  so search this months entries for empty or blank csv. try one out possibly simple test if \TextA="" (i.e. nul entry) \if test{true}{false}

Comment: How big a blank?  [width=3cm, height=3cm]?   \IfFileExists is easy compared to processing keywords.

Comment: @KJO thank for your solution. But i want "transparent" if not image, not white color. Do you other solution, thanks

Comment: @JohnKormylo i think i don't understand your solution. Can you please add to code? Thanks

Comment: latexforti you can add a transparent image even if only same as a web tracker 1x1 pixel and per @JohnKormylo that's good \fileexist {name}{show}{noshow} should work well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution takes advantage of the fact that `\includegraphics` and `\adjustbox` (mostly) use the same keywords.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{file.tex}
 No,TextA
 1,Smile
 2,No
 3,


\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{poster}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{enumitem, setspace}
 \tcbset{colframe=blue!75!black,colback=white}
\DTLloaddb{file}{file.tex}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newcommand{\mygraphics}[2][\empty]% #1 = \includegraphics options, #2=pathname
  {\IfFileExists{#2}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}{\adjustbox{#1}{\rule{1cm}{0pt}\rule{0pt}{1cm}}}}

 \begin{document}

 \DTLforeach*
 {file}% Database
 {\No=No,\TextA=TextA}
 {%
 \begin{tcbposter}[
  poster = {
    columns=1,
    rows=1,
    spacing=3mm,
    height=14cm,
    width=12cm,
  },
]
%Box A

\posterbox[colframe=red,width=4.7cm,height=5.0cm]{name=A,column=1}{

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin =-1em,rightmargin =-1em]
\item \mygraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{ImageA/\TextA.png}  \hfill abc

\end{enumerate}
}
\end{tcbposter}
\newline
}
\end{document}
```